# In SWI-Prolog, what does the number of logical inferences measure?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

In SWI-Prolog, what does the number of logical inferences measure? Is it the number of resolutions, unifications, or other?

To be clear, I am specifically interested in the SWI-Prolog implementation.